# Why is my kitten pooping downstairs?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, toilet-training

We got a kitten a while ago. She was about 8 weeks. We had her litter box downstairs but eventually moved it upstairs because she figured out how to go upstairs and was spending all her time up there. Fast forward a few weeks and she was doing great. She became less fearful in our house and loves attention and playing. All of a sudden she started pooping in our dining room. It is not daily but pushing weekly. When I catch her, after it happens (once we smell it), I put her over by it to look/smell it, then take her to her litter box in the bathroom and shut the door. What more can I do to stop this from happening?

Comment: Probably buy a second litter box to keep at dining room

Comment: Has she been to the vet since the problem started? How old was she when the problem started? How long has it been happening? Is she declawed? Is she desexed? How many litter boxes do you have? What type of litter do you use? Has anything in the house changed? (moved furniture, new pets or roommates?)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate based on the information you've already provided. When you answer the questions I wrote above (you can [edit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/18158/edit) them into your question, we can reopen it.